# How can i access $options variable inside SetDefaultOptions in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was using this fine

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
 {
    $resolver
    ->setDefaults(array(
            'category' => null,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('u');

    if ($someCondition) {
        $qb->where('u.id = $options['id']);
    }

    return $qb;
```

Is there any way to do that becasue i don't want to do in buildform because i am using this in multiple locations

Answer (score 0):

`setDefaultOptions` is intended to initialize options, that will be eventually overwritten by the real passed options, therefore you can't access the `$options` variable there.

If you need to have different default behaviours depending on the runtime values you can still define a method to manage it, but that will have to be called manually during buildform (eventually you can define an abstract buildform and call that function there, then extending classes will have to call parent::buildForm).